# Is there any alternatives for XMLHttpRequest in client server communication

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api, web-development-server

I have a XMLHttpRequest to communicate with an server side .php file (clientserver.php). The request is like,

```
    tablink = tab.url;
    $("#p1").text("Selected URL - "+tablink);
    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    params="url="+tablink;
    // alert(params);
    var markup = "url="+tablink+"&html="+document.documentElement.innerHTML;
    xhr.open("POST","http://localhost/WebExt/clientServer.php",false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(params);
    //alert(xhr.responseText);
    $("#div1").text(xhr.responseText);
    return xhr.responseText;
```

and the clientserver.php contains,

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$site=$_POST['url'];
$decision=exec("python test.py $site 2>&1");
echo $decision;
?>
```

When i executes above code it shows an error like

**Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience**

How to resolve it?
Is there any alternatives codes (Like fetch API) the complete this task (XMLHttpRequest)?

Comment: _"Is there any alternative...?"_ - Yes. Its already in your question: [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: The error message is only telling you that _synchronous_ requests are deprecated - so you don't necessarily need to switch the whole method to something else, but only make the request asynchronous instead. You explicitly specified that you want a synchronous request, by passing `false` as third parameter for the `open` method.

Comment: [From the document by mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#example_http_synchronous_request)  Just remove `false` from `request.open()`.

Answer (score 0):

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest outside of workers is in the process of
> being removed from the web platform as it has detrimental effects to
> the end user’s experience. (This is a long process that takes many
> years.) Developers must not pass false for the async argument when
> current global object is a Window object. User agents are strongly
> encouraged to warn about such usage in developer tools and may
> experiment with throwing an "InvalidAccessError" DOMException when it
> occurs.

https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

If you would like to have some tasks to do **after** XMLHttpRequest then please use [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instead because **Synchronous XMLHttpRequest** will be removed in the future.

Here is an example (test02.php):

```php
<?php
$requestType = ($_GET['requestType'] ?? null);

if (isset($requestType) && $requestType === 'ajax') {
    sleep(1);
    echo 'hello';
    exit();
}
?>

<div id="response" style="border: 4px dashed #ccc;"></div>

<script>
    function ajaxRequest() {
        let promiseObj = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.addEventListener('abort', (event) => {
                reject({'response': '', 'status': (event.currentTarget ? event.currentTarget.status : 'abort'), 'event': event});
            });
            xhr.addEventListener('error', function(event) {
                reject({'response': '', 'status': (event.currentTarget ? event.currentTarget.status : ''), 'event': event});
            });
            xhr.addEventListener('timeout', (event) => {
                reject({'response': '', 'status': (event.currentTarget ? event.currentTarget.status : 'timeout'), 'event': event});
            });
            xhr.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
                let response = (event.currentTarget ? event.currentTarget.response : '');

                if (event.currentTarget && event.currentTarget.status >= 200 && event.currentTarget.status < 300) {
                    resolve({'response': response, 'status': event.currentTarget.status, 'event': event});
                } else if (event.currentTarget && event.currentTarget.status >= 400 && event.currentTarget.status < 600) {
                    reject({'response': response, 'status': event.currentTarget.status, 'event': event});
                } else {
                    reject({'response': response, 'status': event.currentTarget.status, 'event': event});
                }
            });

            xhr.open("POST","test02.php?requestType=ajax");// use your URL.
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            // add your xhr options here.
            xhr.send();
        });

    return promiseObj;
    }
    ajaxRequest()
    .then((response) => {
        let responseElement = document.getElementById('response');
        responseElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', response.response + '<br>');
        responseElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'hi');
    });
</script>
```

This **Asynchronous** request will not freeze user's web browser and the task(s) after this still working fine as queue by `then()`.